# Error while loading hive table using Hcatalog in Pig

Tags: xml, hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I am trying to load my hive table using **Hcatalog** in pig, for that i have written below code but i am getting error. I am opening my pig shell using `pig -useHCatalog`

**Code:**

```
A = LOAD 'patient_info' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

**Error:**

> ERROR hive.ql.metadata.Table - Unable to get field from serde:
>   com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class
>   com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe not found)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:275)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:255)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:602)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getTableSchemaWithPtnCols(HCatUtil.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.getSchema(HCatLoader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.(LOLoad.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:866)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3568)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1625)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
>     at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1688)   at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1635)     at
>   org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:587)    at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:547)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:158)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) Caused by:
>   MetaException(message:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class
>   com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe not found)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:400)

**Update:**

My command for storing data in hive is given below.

```
add jar /home/cloudera/hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE patient_info (
statusCode string,
title string,
startTime string,
endTime string,
frequencyValue string,
frequencyUnits string

)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"column.xpath.statusCode"="medicationsInfo/entryInfo/statusCode/text()",
"column.xpath.title"="medications/code/code/text()",
"column.xpath.startTime"="medications/xxx/startTime/text()",
"column.xpath.endTime"="medications/xxx/endTime/text()",
"column.xpath.frequencyValue"="medications/xxx/frequencyValue/text()",
"column.xpath.frequencyUnits"="medications/xxx/frequencyUnits/text()",
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES (
"xmlinput.start"="<medicationsInfo",
"xmlinput.end"="</medicationsInfo>");


load data inpath '/user/cloudera/xml' into table patient_info ;
```

**Sample:**

```
 <Document>
    <ProductCode>
     <code>10160-0</code>
     <entryInfo> 
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20110729</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>24</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20120130</startTime>
        <endTime>20120326</endTime>
        <strengthValue>12</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo>
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20100412</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>8</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
    </ProductCode>
    <ProductCode>
     <code>10160-0</code>
     <entryInfo> 
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20110729</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>24</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20120130</startTime>
        <endTime>20120326</endTime>
        <strengthValue>12</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo>
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20100412</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>8</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
    </ProductCode> 
   <Medicationsinfo>
     <code>10160-0</code>
     <entryInfo> 
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20110729</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>24</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20120130</startTime>
        <endTime>20120326</endTime>
        <strengthValue>12</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo>
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20100412</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>8</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
    </Medicationsinfo>
    <Medicationsinfo>
     <code>10160-0</code>
     <entryInfo> 
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20110729</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>24</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20120130</startTime>
        <endTime>20120326</endTime>
        <strengthValue>12</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo>
     <entryInfo>
        <statusCode>completed</statusCode>
        <startTime>20100412</startTime>
        <endTime>20110822</endTime>
        <strengthValue>8</strengthValue>
        <strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits>
     </entryInfo> 
    </Medicationsinfo> 
    </Document>
```

Comment: It looks like a hie error, try to select some rows from your table in hive to verify.

Comment: i tried fetching data from hive and i am able to get it.

Comment: can you add the table definition to your question plz ?

Comment: It seems like the XmlSerDe  is not known to pig. Care to  share how you stored the data?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I stored my data by using pig to parse a file in hdfs and than used hive create command for storing the parsed data in hive.

Comment: Please be more specific. I understand that you have loaded the data and processed it using PIG but I'm not clear what happened later. Also please share the relevant command (not the processing but the loading and storing of the data in PIG/Hive)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I have updated my question please check.

Comment: This does not make sense... where did the error on `XmlSerDe ` came from?

Comment: But it looks like you are trying to read a file that was stores with `XmlSerDe ` using PIG

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz i am sorry i gave you wrong explanation. I am using hivexmlserde to store data in hive.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz please help me.

Comment: This still does not make sense. The table you are trying to load with PIG is **patient_info** while the hive table is **medica**

Comment: Also the `load data` to **medica** does not make sense. All you needed to do is define `location '/user/cloudera/xml'` for the external table.

Comment: i added `medica` simply actual code is having `patient_info` i followed what you said but same error is coming. Is this because i am using `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe`

Comment: could you add a small data sample?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz sample i cannot post as my company is having confidential data.

Comment: The real data is not important, only the structure. Just replace the real data with Gibberish.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz i have updated my question please check. Actual data is having huge sub tags that i am not able to bring it up here. Here is sample of it.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not valid since you have multiple entryInfo per Medicationsinfo. You can shred the XML per entryInfo (but then you use the Medicationsinfo info, e.g. code) or you can shre it per Medicationsinfo  but then you have to take entryInfo as an whole xml fragment (without splitting it to fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of your external table is not valid.
Here are some options:

---

#### Option 1

```
create external table patient_info 
(
    code        string
   ,entryInfo   string
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.code"      = "/Medicationsinfo/code/text()"
   ,"column.xpath.entryInfo" = "/Medicationsinfo/entryInfo"
)
stored as
inputformat 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location '/user/hive/warehouse/patient_info'
tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start" = "<Medicationsinfo"
   ,"xmlinput.end"   = "</Medicationsinfo>"
)
;

select * from patient_info
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| patient_info.code | patient_info.entryinfo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10160-0           | <string><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20110729</startTime><endTime>20110822</endTime><strengthValue>24</strengthValue><strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits></entryInfo><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20120130</startTime><endTime>20120326</endTime><strengthValue>12</strengthValue><strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits></entryInfo><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20100412</startTime><endTime>20110822</endTime><strengthValue>8</strengthValue><strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits></entryInfo></string> |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10160-0           | <string><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20110729</startTime><endTime>20110822</endTime><strengthValue>24</strengthValue><strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits></entryInfo><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20120130</startTime><endTime>20120326</endTime><strengthValue>12</strengthValue><strengthUnits>h</strengthUnits></entryInfo><entryInfo><statusCode>completed</statusCode><startTime>20100412</startTime><endTime>20110822</endTime><strengthValue>8</strengthValue><strengthUnits>d</strengthUnits></entryInfo></string> |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Option 2

```
create external table patient_info 
(
    code        string
   ,entryInfo   array<map<string,map<string,string>>>
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.code"      = "/Medicationsinfo/code/text()"
   ,"column.xpath.entryInfo" = "/Medicationsinfo/entryInfo"
)
stored as
inputformat 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location '/user/hive/warehouse/patient_info'
tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start" = "<Medicationsinfo"
   ,"xmlinput.end"   = "</Medicationsinfo>"
)
;

select * from patient_info
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| patient_info.code |                                                                                                                                                                                   patient_info.entryinfo                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10160-0           | [{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20110729","strengthUnits":"h","endTime":"20110822","strengthValue":"24"}},{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20120130","strengthUnits":"h","endTime":"20120326","strengthValue":"12"}},{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20100412","strengthUnits":"d","endTime":"20110822","strengthValue":"8"}}] |
| 10160-0           | [{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20110729","strengthUnits":"h","endTime":"20110822","strengthValue":"24"}},{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20120130","strengthUnits":"h","endTime":"20120326","strengthValue":"12"}},{"entryInfo":{"statusCode":"completed","startTime":"20100412","strengthUnits":"d","endTime":"20110822","strengthValue":"8"}}] |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

#### Option 3

```
create external table patient_info 
(
    code        string
   ,entryInfo   array<map<string,struct<statusCode:string,startTime:string,endTime:string,strengthValue:int,strengthUnits:string>>>
)
row format serde 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
with serdeproperties 
(
    "column.xpath.code"      = "/Medicationsinfo/code/text()"
   ,"column.xpath.entryInfo" = "/Medicationsinfo/entryInfo"
)
stored as
inputformat 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
outputformat 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
location '/user/hive/warehouse/patient_info'
tblproperties 
(
    "xmlinput.start" = "<Medicationsinfo"
   ,"xmlinput.end"   = "</Medicationsinfo>"
)
;

select * from patient_info
;
```

---

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| patient_info.code |                                                                                                                                                                                patient_info.entryinfo                                                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10160-0           | [{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20110729","endtime":"20110822","strengthvalue":24,"strengthunits":"h"}},{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20120130","endtime":"20120326","strengthvalue":12,"strengthunits":"h"}},{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20100412","endtime":"20110822","strengthvalue":8,"strengthunits":"d"}}] |
| 10160-0           | [{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20110729","endtime":"20110822","strengthvalue":24,"strengthunits":"h"}},{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20120130","endtime":"20120326","strengthvalue":12,"strengthunits":"h"}},{"entryInfo":{"statuscode":"completed","starttime":"20100412","endtime":"20110822","strengthvalue":8,"strengthunits":"d"}}] |
+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

#### Explode option 3

```
select  pi.code
       ,ei.i + 1    as i
       ,ei.entryInfo["entryInfo"].statusCode
       ,ei.entryInfo["entryInfo"].startTime
       ,ei.entryInfo["entryInfo"].endTime
       ,ei.entryInfo["entryInfo"].strengthValue
       ,ei.entryInfo["entryInfo"].strengthUnits

from    patient_info    pi
        lateral view  posexplode (entryInfo) ei as i,entryInfo
;
```

---

```
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| pi.code | i | statuscode | starttime | endtime  | strengthvalue | strengthunits |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 1 | completed  | 20110729  | 20110822 | 24            | h             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 2 | completed  | 20120130  | 20120326 | 12            | h             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 3 | completed  | 20100412  | 20110822 | 8             | d             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 1 | completed  | 20110729  | 20110822 | 24            | h             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 2 | completed  | 20120130  | 20120326 | 12            | h             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 10160-0 | 3 | completed  | 20100412  | 20110822 | 8             | d             |
+---------+---+------------+-----------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: i need my results in column wise format but in these cases i am getting my results in one single row. How can i than pick particular strength value that i needed. If you please help me with that.

Comment: Thanks. I am waiting for it. I am accepting your answer your helped a lot to me.

Comment: can you explain me why you used `ei.i + 1`

Comment: posexplode starts with 0 and I thought it would be more human readable to see a sequence of 1,2,3,... over 0,1,2...

Comment: Got it, Thanks for quick response.